# Chrome - Strange Dispaly Issues w. Ajax Requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, google-chrome

I am working on a large web application.

It's been in production now for close to 2 years.

Recently, we have started getting complaints from users regarding some weird display issues.

It seems on certain screens(random as far as I can tell), when  Ajax requests being made there is a weird flickering graphic that appears.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I don't believe this to be a CSS/JS issue.

- All of our users use the latest version of chrome
- We use Kendo UI and Jquery, but no other frameworks
- It happens frequently, but is unrepeatable
- It affects multiple users across a number of computers

Has anyone experienced this, or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't resolve the actual problem, but fixes the issue.  It appears to be an issue with the Chrome setting "User Hardware Acceleration". Shutting this off fixes the problem.

Hopefully a good performance analysis and some refactoring will fix the problem and allow me to turn this feature back on.